# mock post method npm request module with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, fetch

I know that [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module is now deprecated, but i want to mock a post http call with jest.

Here is my function

```
import { post } from 'request'; 

export functionToFetch(uriFetching) {

    return post(
        {
            url: uriFetching,
            headers: {},
            json,
        },

        (error, response, body) => {

            if (error) {
                console.log('error)
                // return specific code
            }
              // return success code

            
        }

}
```

And in try this in my test :

```
import { post } from 'request';
import {functionToFetch} from './example';

it('should do some specific handling on error', () => {
    const fakeURI = 'http://example.com'
    
    request.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(new Response('test')));

    // on error
    expect(functionToFetch(fakeURI).toEqual(expected);
    // on success
    expect(functionToFetch(fakeURI).toEqual(expected2);

});
```

But it returns TypeError: Cannot set property 'post' of undefined

I want to mock that method to handle error and response to test methods inside them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jest.mock()` and `post.mockImplementation()` will do this. You can get the actual callback function passed in `post` function in your test case. And execute it manually with mocked arguments.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import { post } from 'request';

export function functionToFetch(uriFetching) {
  const json = {};

  post({ url: uriFetching, headers: {}, json }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { functionToFetch } from '.';
import { post } from 'request';

jest.mock('request');

describe('67210149', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should do some specific handling on error', () => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    post.mockImplementation((option, callback) => {
      callback(mError);
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const fakeURI = 'http://example.com';
    functionToFetch(fakeURI);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mError);
    expect(post).toBeCalledWith({ url: 'http://example.com', headers: {}, json: {} }, expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67210149/index.test.js (7.274 s)
  67210149
    ✓ should do some specific handling on error (24 ms)

  console.log
    Error: network
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/examples/67210149/index.test.js:8:20)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)
        at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
        at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.836 s, estimated 8 s
```